# Time-shifting and time-scaling of Fourier transform $x(t) = \text{rect} \big(\frac{t}{2}-\frac{3}{2}\big)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Consider $$x(t) = \text{rect} \left(\frac{t}{2}-\frac{3}{2}\right)$$

From FT-Table, we know $$\mathcal{F}\big(x(at)\big) = \frac{1}{|a|}X\left(j\frac{\omega}{a}\right)$$ and
$$\mathcal{F}\big(x(t-t_0)\big) = X\left(j\omega\right)e^{-j\omega t_0}$$

Now I am confused the FT of the top function should be $$X(j\omega)=2\text{sinc}\left(\frac{\omega}{\pi}\right)e^{-j\omega \frac{3}{2}}$$ or $$X(j\omega)=2\text{sinc}\left(\frac{\omega}{\pi}\right)e^{-j\omega 3}$$

Can anyone please provide me with a strict way to identify the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, take$$X(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{t}{\tau}\right) e^{-j \omega t} d t$$
$\text { Since rect }(t / \tau)=1 \text { for }-\tau / 2<t<\tau / 2 \text { and } 0 \text { otherwise, we have }
 $
$$X(\omega)=\int_{-\tau / 2}^{\tau / 2} e^{-j \omega t} d t=-\frac{1}{j \omega}\left(e^{-j \omega r / 2}-e^{j \omega r / 2}\right)=\frac{2 \sin \left(\frac{\omega \tau}{2}\right)}{\omega}=\tau \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\omega \tau}{2}\right)}{\left(\frac{\omega \tau}{2}\right)}=\tau \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{\omega \tau}{2}\right).$$
We take $\tau=2$, thus $X(\omega)=2\text{sinc}(\omega).$ Subsequently, the translation rule you give us
$$ 2\text{sinc}(\omega)e^{- 3j  \omega   },$$ since we translate by 3.
You take another definition of rect that gives us the $1/\pi$?

Also:
I presume $X=\mathcal F(x),$ so be aware the transformation rules read
$$\mathcal F(f(at))=\frac1{|a|}\hat f(\frac \omega{|a|})$$
and
$$\mathcal F(f(t-t_0))= \hat f(\omega )e^{-jt_0\omega},$$ where $\hat f=\mathcal F(f)$, thus the complex number $j$ is not within $f$.

Comment: I agree with your answer. However, when I use WolframAlpha to calculate it, I get "$e^{-j3\omega}$".

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier+transform+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22transformfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22rect%28%28t-3%29%2F2%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable1%22%7D+-%3E%22t%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable2%22%7D+-%3E%22w%22

Comment: @Denny Because $f(t) = \text{rect}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$ in the answer. We get $f(t-3) = \text{rect}\left(\frac{t}{2}-\frac{3}{2}\right)$ so indeed $\hat{f}(w)e^{-3iw}$ is correct

Comment: @AndréArmatowski Thanks!

Comment: @AndréArmatowski Good observation. We translate by 3 indeed, I edited my post.